# MonthName is not working

Tags: function, asp-classic

when i was writing my code in asp file,

response.write MonthName(8,true)

it display:

8��

instead of :

Aug

why??

Comment: What are your regional settings?

Comment: short date: dd/MM/yyyy
long date: d MMMM,yyyy
short time: h:mm tt
long time: h:mm:ss tt
first day of the week: Sunday

Comment: Any chance you changed the LCID somewhere?

Comment: how do i check my lcid and how does it actually affect the function?

Comment: thanks @ShadowWizard i change the lcid in my iis settings and all working now! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Session.LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525071%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is affecting various things, the date/time display is one of those things.

If somehow the default LCID is wrong, you can override it by code on any page where you need it:

```vbs
Session.LCID = 1033 'just example for English, US
```

Full list of values can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) and I'll copy it here as well. (Microsoft move/delete pages sometimes thus can't be trusted as reliable host for code)

```
Language - Country/Region   LCID Hex    LCID Dec
Afrikaans - South Africa    0436    1078
Albanian - Albania  041c    1052
Alsatian    0484    1156
Amharic - Ethiopia  045e    1118
Arabic - Saudi Arabia   0401    1025
Arabic - Algeria    1401    5121
Arabic - Bahrain    3c01    15361
Arabic - Egypt  0c01    3073
Arabic - Iraq   0801    2049
Arabic - Jordan 2c01    11265
Arabic - Kuwait 3401    13313
Arabic - Lebanon    3001    12289
Arabic - Libya  1001    4097
Arabic - Morocco    1801    6145
Arabic - Oman   2001    8193
Arabic - Qatar  4001    16385
Arabic - Syria  2801    10241
Arabic - Tunisia    1c01    7169
Arabic - U.A.E. 3801    14337
Arabic - Yemen  2401    9217
Armenian - Armenia  042b    1067
Assamese    044d    1101
Azeri (Cyrillic)    082c    2092
Azeri (Latin)   042c    1068
Bashkir 046d    1133
Basque  042d    1069
Belarusian  0423    1059
Bengali (India) 0445    1093
Bengali (Bangladesh)    0845    2117
Bosnian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)    141A    5146
Breton  047e    1150
Bulgarian   0402    1026
Burmese 0455    1109
Catalan 0403    1027
Cherokee - United States    045c    1116
Chinese - People's Republic of China    0804    2052
Chinese - Singapore 1004    4100
Chinese - Taiwan    0404    1028
Chinese - Hong Kong SAR 0c04    3076
Chinese - Macao SAR 1404    5124
Corsican    0483    1155
Croatian    041a    1050
Croatian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)   101a    4122
Czech   0405    1029
Danish  0406    1030
Dari    048c    1164
Divehi  0465    1125
Dutch - Netherlands 0413    1043
Dutch - Belgium 0813    2067
Edo 0466    1126
English - United States 0409    1033
English - United Kingdom    0809    2057
English - Australia 0c09    3081
English - Belize    2809    10249
English - Canada    1009    4105
English - Caribbean 2409    9225
English - Hong Kong SAR 3c09    15369
English - India 4009    16393
English - Indonesia 3809    14345
English - Ireland   1809    6153
English - Jamaica   2009    8201
English - Malaysia  4409    17417
English - New Zealand   1409    5129
English - Philippines   3409    13321
English - Singapore 4809    18441
English - South Africa  1c09    7177
English - Trinidad  2c09    11273
English - Zimbabwe  3009    12297
Estonian    0425    1061
Faroese 0438    1080
Farsi   0429    1065
Filipino    0464    1124
Finnish 040b    1035
French - France 040c    1036
French - Belgium    080c    2060
French - Cameroon   2c0c    11276
French - Canada 0c0c    3084
French - Democratic Rep. of Congo   240c    9228
French - Cote d'Ivoire  300c    12300
French - Haiti  3c0c    15372
French - Luxembourg 140c    5132
French - Mali   340c    13324
French - Monaco 180c    6156
French - Morocco    380c    14348
French - North Africa   e40c    58380
French - Reunion    200c    8204
French - Senegal    280c    10252
French - Switzerland    100c    4108
French - West Indies    1c0c    7180
Frisian - Netherlands   0462    1122
Fulfulde - Nigeria  0467    1127
FYRO Macedonian 042f    1071
Galician    0456    1110
Georgian    0437    1079
German - Germany    0407    1031
German - Austria    0c07    3079
German - Liechtenstein  1407    5127
German - Luxembourg 1007    4103
German - Switzerland    0807    2055
Greek   0408    1032
Greenlandic 046f    1135
Guarani - Paraguay  0474    1140
Gujarati    0447    1095
Hausa - Nigeria 0468    1128
Hawaiian - United States    0475    1141
Hebrew  040d    1037
Hindi   0439    1081
Hungarian   040e    1038
Ibibio - Nigeria    0469    1129
Icelandic   040f    1039
Igbo - Nigeria  0470    1136
Indonesian  0421    1057
Inuktitut   045d    1117
Irish   083c    2108
Italian - Italy 0410    1040
Italian - Switzerland   0810    2064
Japanese    0411    1041
K'iche  0486    1158
Kannada 044b    1099
Kanuri - Nigeria    0471    1137
Kashmiri    0860    2144
Kashmiri (Arabic)   0460    1120
Kazakh  043f    1087
Khmer   0453    1107
Kinyarwanda 0487    1159
Konkani 0457    1111
Korean  0412    1042
Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)   0440    1088
Lao 0454    1108
Latin   0476    1142
Latvian 0426    1062
Lithuanian  0427    1063
Luxembourgish   046e    1134
Malay - Malaysia    043e    1086
Malay - Brunei Darussalam   083e    2110
Malayalam   044c    1100
Maltese 043a    1082
Manipuri    0458    1112
Maori - New Zealand 0481    1153
Mapudungun  0471    1146
Marathi 044e    1102
Mohawk  047c    1148
Mongolian (Cyrillic)    0450    1104
Mongolian (Mongolian)   0850    2128
Nepali  0461    1121
Nepali - India  0861    2145
Norwegian (Bokmål)  0414    1044
Norwegian (Nynorsk) 0814    2068
Occitan 0482    1154
Oriya   0448    1096
Oromo   0472    1138
Papiamentu  0479    1145
Pashto  0463    1123
Polish  0415    1045
Portuguese - Brazil 0416    1046
Portuguese - Portugal   0816    2070
Punjabi 0446    1094
Punjabi (Pakistan)  0846    2118
Quecha - Bolivia    046B    1131
Quecha - Ecuador    086B    2155
Quecha - Peru   0C6B    3179
Rhaeto-Romanic  0417    1047
Romanian    0418    1048
Romanian - Moldava  0818    2072
Russian 0419    1049
Russian - Moldava   0819    2073
Sami (Lappish)  043b    1083
Sanskrit    044f    1103
Scottish Gaelic 043c    1084
Sepedi  046c    1132
Serbian (Cyrillic)  0c1a    3098
Serbian (Latin) 081a    2074
Sindhi - India  0459    1113
Sindhi - Pakistan   0859    2137
Sinhalese - Sri Lanka   045b    1115
Slovak  041b    1051
Slovenian   0424    1060
Somali  0477    1143
Sorbian 042e    1070
Spanish - Spain (Modern Sort)   0c0a    3082
Spanish - Spain (Traditional Sort)  040a    1034
Spanish - Argentina 2c0a    11274
Spanish - Bolivia   400a    16394
Spanish - Chile 340a    13322
Spanish - Colombia  240a    9226
Spanish - Costa Rica    140a    5130
Spanish - Dominican Republic    1c0a    7178
Spanish - Ecuador   300a    12298
Spanish - El Salvador   440a    17418
Spanish - Guatemala 100a    4106
Spanish - Honduras  480a    18442
Spanish - Latin America 580a    22538
Spanish - Mexico    080a    2058
Spanish - Nicaragua 4c0a    19466
Spanish - Panama    180a    6154
Spanish - Paraguay  3c0a    15370
Spanish - Peru  280a    10250
Spanish - Puerto Rico   500a    20490
Spanish - United States 540a    21514
Spanish - Uruguay   380a    14346
Spanish - Venezuela 200a    8202
Sutu    0430    1072
Swahili 0441    1089
Swedish 041d    1053
Swedish - Finland   081d    2077
Syriac  045a    1114
Tajik   0428    1064
Tamazight (Arabic)  045f    1119
Tamazight (Latin)   085f    2143
Tamil   0449    1097
Tatar   0444    1092
Telugu  044a    1098
Thai    041e    1054
Tibetan - Bhutan    0851    2129
Tibetan - People's Republic of China    0451    1105
Tigrigna - Eritrea  0873    2163
Tigrigna - Ethiopia 0473    1139
Tsonga  0431    1073
Tswana  0432    1074
Turkish 041f    1055
Turkmen 0442    1090
Uighur - China  0480    1152
Ukrainian   0422    1058
Urdu    0420    1056
Urdu - India    0820    2080
Uzbek (Cyrillic)    0843    2115
Uzbek (Latin)   0443    1091
Venda   0433    1075
Vietnamese  042a    1066
Welsh   0452    1106
Wolof   0488    1160
Xhosa   0434    1076
Yakut   0485    1157
Yi  0478    1144
Yiddish 043d    1085
Yoruba  046a    1130
Zulu    0435    1077
HID (Human Interface Device)    04ff    1279
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed when changing the display language of a page to French (Canada).  I will have to keep this in mind for displaying dates as well, as you mentioned.